# Function call in another namespace and class

Tags: c#, class, call

I like to connect the DLL (which contains namespace `Chart`) and call the subroutine `public Simple()` from the second class (namespace `WinApp2`). There is a error:

> couldn't find type or namespace name Simple

Although I consider a reference and put `using Chart` and created a instance in the second namespace.

```
namespace Chart
{
    public partial class Simple : Form
    {
        Manage _mProject;
        public Simple()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _mProject = new Manage();
            _mProject.Add(new Task() { Name = "New Task" });
            _mChart.Init(_mProject);
        }
    }
}

using Chart;
namespace WinApp2
{
    public partial class Form4 : Form
    {
        Form2 fh;
        public Form4(Form2 aufrufer)
        {
          fh = aufrufer;
          InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          var instance = new Simple();   (error !!!)
          instance.Simple();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the error appears on `new Simple` instead of `instance.Simple`? The latter won´t compile as `Simple()` is a constructor, not a method.

Comment: MegaTron, I connected the DLL source file in the VS project file ..

Comment: HimBromBeere, Yes it's the var instance = new Simple(); line which bring the error ..

Comment: @joe try to remove line `instance.Simple();` and check again

Comment: MegTron, No difference. It's still idicating and error that Type or Namespace name "Simple" couldn't be found (missing a using-Directive or a Assembly reference?).

Comment: Or is the issue related to the partial class definition ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by "consider a reference and put using Chart" ? Did you actually include the dll in References section, or did you put using Chart and think that will reference the relevant dll?

The proper steps are:

- Right click References section in VS
- Choose Add Reference
- Browse to location of relevant dll, choose OK

Another cause may be that Chart is a defined class in System.Web.DataVisualization.dll, so VS is confused. Try changing your Chart namespace to something else, e.g., MyChart

Hope this helps..

Comment: Minh, I followed your steps, but it still indicates the error CS0246: Type or Namespace name "Simple" couldn't be found (missing a using-Directive or a Assembly reference?). Obviously the using Chart was correctly be found so that must be any refereence.

Comment: Minh, the line <var instance = new Simple();> shows no problems now, which indicates that obviously the DLL must correctly referenced (or not?). But the second line <instance.Simple();> has now an error that Simple() has no definition for Simple();. Is it a problem if the class has the same name than the subroutine .. ?

Comment: You can't call instance.Simple() because Simple is not a method, but rather, it's a default constructor, called when you instantiate the class, as @HimBromBeere has correctly pointed out

Comment: Just delete that instance.Simple() line, and everything should work as expected

Comment: Minh, Ok I got it now what you and HimBromBeere mentioned about the constructor. Thanks.